# Ubuntu 20.04 is stuck on "Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f" after sleep

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, suspend, crash

Ever since I updated from 18 LTS to Ubuntu 20 LTS this has been happening 90% of the time I close my monitor lid and when I open up the lid to reactivate my computer from sleep it would be stuck on the screen in the picture below. I've tried some things I found online, unfortunately no one directly has my problem. Any help would be appreciated, or else I'll probably wipe and reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04.

Error message:

[image: Error message]

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you been able to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried upgrading to the newest Ubuntu 21 and sitll the same issue. Probably have to completely reinstall and downgrade to 18 LTS feelsbadman.

Comment: I solved it by downgrading my nvidia driver. Just make sure that you install the nvidia driver from terminal and not from GUI.

Comment: Contact the fabricant of your pc if is not a pc custom (i think)

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu22.04LTS desktop
MBoard:z490
wifi:ax200
log:Bluetooth: hci0: Received unexpected HCI Event 0x00

```
It is a not good idea solution:
1,sudo service bluetooth restart
[may be you should sudo bluetoothctl disconnect [bluetoothId]]
2,sudo bluetoothctl power off
3,sudo bluetoothctl power on
4,sudo bluetoothctl connect [bluetoothId]
```

maybe protocal 5+ bluetooth not stable

Comment: I use my phone to connect to Bluetooth device instead of Ubuntu because The solution not always work